# Get y set, Ya sabe que me estoy refiriendo a la variable privada nombre?

Tags: c#

Lo que quiero preguntar es que si poniendo así como muestro en la imagen, el programa ya sabe que me refiero a la variable nombre, cuando pongo Nombre con N mayúscula...
o conviene especificarlo para que se dé cuenta, por ejemplo:

```cs
public string Apellido
{
     get { return apellido; }
     set { apellido = value; }
}
```

Colocando return "apellido"---> variable

```cs
class Cliente
{
    private string nombre;
    private string apellido;
    private string teléfono;
    private int tarjetaCredito;

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hola Federica, bienvenida, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y adjuntes tu código como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Answer (score 3):

Solo necesitas colocar esto:

```
public string Nombre { get;set;}
```

Sin colocar ninguna variable privada ni nada. El código de arriba es lo que se conoce como "azúcar sintáctico", esto se compila en un código intermedio y crea automáticamente la variable por ti (tu sin haberla colocado), generando internamente un código similar al siguiente:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private string <Nombre>k__BackingField;

public string Nombre
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return <Nombre>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        <Nombre>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```

Y para que quede más claro, tu clase `Cliente` debería ser:

```
class Cliente{
   public string Nombre { get;set;}
   public string Apellido{ get;set;}
   public string Telefono{ get;set;}
   public int TarjetaCredito{ get;set;}
}
```

---

Por otro lado cabe recordar que los nombres de variables en C# son  "case sensitive", es decir que para todo efecto "Nombre" y "nombre" son cosas distintas y sin relación

Comment: ah perfecto! .. pero mi duda ahora surge que si pongo:

Comment: Okey! muchas gracias.. ahora mi duda es entonces: si yo aplico directamente en una sola linea colocar > public string nombre {get; set;} la estare haciendo publica y no privada, osea es muy redundante igual, se le puede poner el acceso solo a las que sean necesarias y a las demas no..

Comment: @FedericaAlem A que te refieres con "redundante" ???

Comment: Cabe mencionar que no puedes acceder directamente a la variable generada automáticamente por el compilador.

Comment: @Mateo Por ahora no, se espera que pronto lo sea https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140

Answer (score -1):

Son dos cosas distintas:
en tu caso nombre es una variable privada como has indicado pero luego creas la propiedad de acceso publico:
public string Nombre { get; set; }